# Pass multidimensional arrays from Python to DLL

Tags: python, arrays, dll

I have this function in a DLL.

```
int triangle_in_bb_check_int(float* p_bb1, float* p_bb2, float** p_vertices)
```

And then I have this code in Python, were I populate some arrays and try to pass them into this DLL function (note I'm not sure what to put in the 3rd parameter).

```
bbbox1 = [0 for x in range(3)] 
bbbox2 = [0 for x in range(3)] 
triangle_vertex = [[0 for x in range(3)] for y in range(3)] 

#... populate the data above with floats

mydll = windll.LoadLibrary("GA_Tools.dll")
mydll.restype = c_int
mydll.triangle_in_bb_check_int.argtypes = [POINTER(c_float), POINTER(c_float), ????]
mydll.triangle_in_bb_check_int(bbbox1, bbbox2, triangle_vertex)
```

How could I pass the multidimensional array **triangle_vertex** to the DLL function correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to convert your list:

```
import ctypes as ct

def float_list(lst):
    if isinstance(lst[0], list):
        data = [float_list(row) for row in lst]
        return (ct.POINTER(ct.c_float) * len(lst))(*data)
    return (ct.c_float * len(lst))(*lst)
```

This works just for passing the list. You won't be able to alter its content from inside the C function.

In `argtypes` you just add `type(triangle_vertex)`.

Edit: How to use:

```
from ctypes import *

# Create and fill your lists

def float_list(lst):
    if isinstance(lst[0], list):
        data = [float_list(row) for row in lst]
        return (POINTER(c_float) * len(lst))(*data)
    return (c_float * len(lst))(*lst)

arg1 = float_list(bbbox1)
arg2 = float_list(bbbox2)
arg3 = float_list(triangle_vertex)

mydll = windll.LoadLibrary("GA_Tools.dll")
mydll.restype = c_int
mydll.triangle_in_bb_check_int.argtypes = [type(arg1), type(arg2), type(arg3)]
result = mydll.triangle_in_bb_check_int(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

The function turns a 1d list into a `c_float_Array` object (which in C can be called as a single pointer) and a 2d list into a `LP_c_float_Array` (which can be called as a double pointer).

Comment: Thanks! I'm not very familiar with Python, that´s one of the reasons I'm trying to move this to a DLL :P.

What does this exaclty do if you don't mind explaining a bit?

Then I would have to replace the old code with this?
mydll.triangle_in_bb_check_int(self.float_list(bbbox1), self.float_list(bbbox2), self.float_list(triangle_vertex))

Comment: I added what you've requested. Hope it works, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Unfortunately I cannot make it work. This is what I get when I execute it: "ValueError: Procedure probably called with too many arguments (12 bytes in excess)". :(

Comment: Apparently changing "windll.LoadLibrary",for "CDLL" did the job. I will come back if I find further issue, thanks again!